# What Mac app has a red icon with right arrow?

Tags: macos, applications

What Mac app does this icon belong to?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be [Skitch](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch-snap-mark-up-share/id425955336?mt=12), an app for marking up images.